# How to change the path of the photo I clicked on, event.target?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I am new at Vue, so don't judge)

```
<Template>
    <div>
        <img :src="imgPath" @click="changePath(imgPath)">
        <img :src="imgPath" @click="changePath(imgPath)">
        <img :src="imgPath" @click="changePath(imgPath)">
    </div>
</Template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        imgPath: require('../assets/img/photo_1.png'),
        imgPath1: require('../assets/img/photo_1.png'),
        imgPath2: require('../assets/img/photo_2.png'),
    }),

    methods: {
        changeAnswerImgN(imgPath) {
            if (imgPath == this.imgPath1) {
                this.imgPath = this.imgPath2;

            } else if (imgPath == this.imgPath2) {
                this.imgPath = this.imgPath1;
            }
        },
    },

    mounetd() {
        this.imgPath = this.imgPath1;
    },
}
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click on any of the photos they change the path together, but I only want to change the path of the photo I clicked on.

I tried to use `event.target` & `$emit`, but nothing had happened(

Comment: you should bind the 3 images to same data propetry. as soon as `imgPath` changed the the all images src will change. you can either bind them to different data properties and change them accordingly or touch the dom directly (not recommend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect use with an array, since now you are toggling just one value `imgPath`, which of course when you click on one image, all changes. So consider an array, which you iterate in template, and on click, change just that image source value:

```js
data: () => ({
  imgPath1: require('../assets/img/photo_1.png'),
  imgPath2: require('../assets/img/photo_2.png'),
  // iterate this in template
  imgs: []
}),
methods: {
  changePath(img, index) {
    // toggle between the two images
    let newPath = img === this.path1 ? this.path2 : this.path1;
    // needed for change detection
    this.$set(this.imgs, index, newPath);
  }
},
mounted() {
  // you want all images to initially be the first
  this.imgs = Array(3).fill(this.imgPath1);
}
```

and template:

```html
<template v-for="(img, i) in imgs">
  <img :src="img" :key="i" @click="changePath(img, i)">
</template>
```

**[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-platform-xfbyp)**